# Large image upload from Horizon will be saving state forever

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I am running openstack icehouse and trying to upload a 16 GB image from horizon.
Horizon and Glance are running on seperate machines.

The image is fully copied to Glance Node(checked by verifying image file size under /var/lib/glance/images/). But the image status continues to be in saving state forever, The status does not become active.

The output of nova image-show displays.
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property | Value |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| OS-EXT-IMG-SIZE:size | 16947544064 |
| created | 2014-11-06T13:26:25Z |
| id | 46f6218d-2f17-493a-8bc9-a46562cbefff |
| minDisk | 0 |
| minRam | 0 |
| name | very_huge_image |
| progress | 50 |
| status | SAVING |
| updated | 2014-11-06T13:26:25Z |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+

But when I try to upload same image with Glance CLI from horizon machine then in some time image status becomes active and ready to use.

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, but even with a smaller image (1 GB).